# UPDATE and Set Database don't work

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying in about 2 hour to make the query work in my php script ,but nothing happent exept that the 1st row in my table change the value :

```
     <?php
 include_once('connect.php');
echo mysql_error();
    if(isset($_GET['edit'])){
        $Matricule = $_GET['edit'];
        $res = mysql_query("select etudiant.`Matricule`,etudiant.`Nom_Etudiant`,etudiant.`Prenom_Etudiant`,evaluation.`Td`,evaluation.`Tp`,evaluation.`Exam` from etudiant,evaluation where etudiant.`Matricule`=evaluation.`Matricule`;");
        $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
    }
    echo mysql_error();
    if(isset($_POST['Td'])){
        $Td = $_POST['Td'];
        $Matricule = $_POST['Matricule'];
        $sql = "UPDATE evaluation SET Td='$Td' WHERE Matricule='$Matricule'";
        //$sql = "UPDATE `evaluation` SET `Td=15 WHERE `Matricule`=1";
        $res = mysql_query($sql) or die("Could not update".mysql_error());

            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=note-on.php'>";
    echo $sql;
    }
   ?>
 <form action="edit.php" method="POST">
TD: <input type="text" name="Td" value="<?php echo $rows[1];?>"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="Matricule" value="<?php echo $rows[Matricule];?>">
<input type="submit" value="Edit">
 </form>
```

like u see in the script and everytime i click on edit and change the value the 1st row just change even that i am editing the other rows and it's giving a message after i clicked in the edit buttom

UPDATE evaluation SET Td='11' WHERE Matricule='1'

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: You are updating `where marticule='1'` why do you expect it to update more than 1 row?

Comment: maybe if you explain more what are you trying to do, somebody can help

Comment: this is my table :http://www7.0zz0.com/2014/04/26/21/720160794.jpg i am trying to edit every value seperatly

Comment: CodeBird is not u my friend i am talking with Marc B ,he asked me why i opened another subject !

Comment: I think what you're doing wrong is that in your `if(isset($_GET['edit'])` in the `select statement` you are not selecting `WHERE something='$marticule'` so you are always getting the first row, which makes you edit always row 1... and `Marc B` is opening your eyes on an important thing, that's all

Comment: hey my friend thanks for your reply ,i am newbie in web devolopment ,i just saw a video do this and it's worked for him ,but it work juts for the 1st row ,maybe the problem is that i have a split database , i mean my database "a_database" and it has a split tables on it ,so etudiant.`Matricule` and evaluation.`Td` i hope my comment help u to give me a answer and i am verry thankfull for trying to help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
$res = mysql_query("select etudiant.`Matricule`,etudiant.`Nom_Etudiant`,etudiant.`Prenom_Etudiant`,evaluation.`Td`,evaluation.`Tp`,evaluation.`Exam` from etudiant,evaluation where etudiant.`Matricule`=evaluation.`Matricule`;");
```

By this:

```
$res = mysql_query("select etudiant.`Matricule`,etudiant.`Nom_Etudiant`,etudiant.`Prenom_Etudiant`,evaluation.`Td`,evaluation.`Tp`,evaluation.`Exam` from etudiant INNER JOIN evaluation ON etudiant.`Matricule`=evaluation.`Matricule` WHERE etudiant.`Matricule`='$Matricule'");
```

And if you are a newbie, so you're still learning, it is better not to be learning deprecated stuff like mysql_*. Check tutorials and videos with PDO or mysqli and prepared statements.

**EDIT**

As stated in my comment above, your problem is that you're not selecting where Marticule=$Marticule, which you're sending in the `$_GET`, you were just selecting the first row of the table that's why you were then always updating the first row no matter which edit you click. => this is what made the difference `WHERE etudiant.`Matricule`='$Matricule'`

As for how to echo the name of the etudiant, what you're doing wrong is that you're trying to `echo $rows[2]` when you're using `mysql_fetch_assoc`, so `$rows` has no 0, 1, 2, ... indices, it has column_names as indices. So if you want to get `Nom_Etudiant` you use `$rows['Nom_Etudiant'];`

so your code becomes like this:

```
<input type="text" name="Td" value="<?php echo $rows['Td'];?>">
```

Comment: thanks CodeBird ,but i am learning this because it's for my final study project so i am really in hurry that's why i am watching videos ,and it worked thanks a lot my friend u r awesome ,can u tell what was the problem ,and still one little thing how to echo the td value on the box , wright now it's echo the Name or somthing this is the script :<input type="text" name="Td" value="<?php echo $rows[2];?>"><br>

Comment: @user3566692 I updated my answer, hope it helps. I have to leave so won't be able to answer anymore.

Comment: ok thanks CodeBird ,it really worked ,and if u come can u tell do i have to the same thing with the 2 fields "TD","Exam" and do i have to create another file or should i just add the script with the Td edit thanks